# Foreign Telegraphic Transfer: Correct IBAN but with a different bank SWIFT CODE

Tags: wire-transfer, swift, iban

I have sent quite a large amount of money (in MYR) to Singapore from Malaysia. The IBAN is correct (recipient's bank is SINGAPORE OCBC with an OCBC account number) but unfortunately, for the swift code, I have put a completely different bank swift code (MAYBANK SINGAPORE swift code instead of OCBC SINGAPORE swift code). The recipient did not get the money and the money is not refunded to my account either. It's been more than 2 weeks. Can it be fixed during the process? Can I get my money transferred back to my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the money is stuck Maybank Singapore. Generally they would have sent a query to your bank in Malaysia....

Best is raise a complaint with your bank and they should be able to help you.

Funds will be returned to you only when Maybank returns it. This can take a while.